# Problem with ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS django 2.1

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-2.1

I started to create login module in django. Login module is ok but I have problem with logout. When i click Logout - we see "error -ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS"

Probably something in this file is incorect: account/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from . import views

app_name = 'account'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='account/login.html'), name='login'),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='registration/logout.html'), name='logout'),
    path('logout-then-login/', auth_views.logout_then_login, name='logout_then_login'),
    path('dashboard/', views.dashboard, name='dashboard'),
```

base.html

```
<body>
  <div id="header">
  {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
    <ul class="menu">
      <li {% if section == "dashboard" %} class="selected"{% endif %}>
        <a href="{% url "account:dashboard" %}">Panel główny</a>
      </li>
      <li {% if section == "images" %} class="selected"{% endif %}>
        <a href="#">Obrazy</a>
      </li>
      <li {% if section == "people" %} class="selected"{% endif %}>
        <a href="#">Ludzie</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  {% endif %}

    <span class="user">
        {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
            Witaj, {{ request.user.first_name }}
            <a href="{% url "account:logout" %}">Wyloguj</a>
        {% else %}
            <a href="{% url "account:login" %}">Zaloguj</a>
        {% endif %}
    </span>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}
    </div>
</body>
```

logout.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %} Wylogowanie {% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Wylogowanie</h1>
    <p>Zostales wylogowany. Mozesz
        <a href="{% url "account:login" %}">zalogowac sie ponownie</a></p>
{% endblock %}
```

settings.html

```
...
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = reverse_lazy('account:dashboard')
LOGIN_URL = reverse_lazy('account:login')
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = reverse_lazy('account:logout')
```

[show error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88j7I.png)

Comment: Did you modify the logout view at all? I suspect it has something to do with your logout_then_login view, but would have to see more code.

Comment: add logout.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've set `LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL` to point back to the `LogoutView` which will cause a redirect loop. The `LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL` [should point to a URL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#logout-redirect-url) that the user will be redirected to *after* they've logged out using the `LogoutView`.

Setting `LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL` will override any template that's been set. Since you've explicitly set a template for the `LogoutView` in your `urls.py`, you should remove `LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL` from your settings which will allow the template to be rendered.